# Is $\left\{f\in L^1(\mu)\colon\int_{\mathbb R} |f(x)|^2d\mu\ge 1\right\}$ a closed set of $L^1(\mu)$?

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$. Let
>   \begin{align}
> A:=&\left\{f\in L^1(\mu)\colon\int_{\mathbb R} |f(x)|^2d\mu\ge 1\right\},\\
> B:=&\left\{f\in L^1(\mu)\colon\int_{\mathbb R} |f(x)|^2d\mu\le 1\right\}.
> \end{align}
>
> 1. Is $A$ a closed subset of $L^1(\mu)$?
> 2. Is $B$ a closed subset of $L^1(\mu)$?

---

My attempt:

First, let's consider 1. Suppose $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of functions in $L^1(\mu)$ satisfying $\int_{\mathbb R}|f_n(x)|^2d\mu\ge 1$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb R}|f_n(x)-f(x)|d\mu=0$ we want to show that either $\int_{\mathbb R}|f(x)|^2d\mu\ge 1$ or there exists a sequence of $\{f_n\}$ with $\int_{\mathbb R}|f(x)|^2d\mu< 1$.

I have tried to apply some basic techniques like:
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb R}|f(x)|^2d\mu&=\int_{\mathbb R}|f(x)-f_n(x)+f_n(x)|^2d\mu\\
\end{align}
But then I got stuck. My problem is I am not able to fit the $L^1$ norm of $f_n-f$ and the $L^2$ norm of $f_n$ together. Can someone give me a hint? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1). No. Consider $f_n(x) = \sqrt{n}1_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}(x)$. Then $\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f_n(x)|^2dx = 1$ for each $n$ whilst $f_n \to 0$ in $L^1$.

2). Yes. Say $(f_n)_n \in B$ and $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$. Then some subsequence $f_{n_k} \to f$ pointwise a.e.. Fatou's Lemma implies $\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f(x)|^2dx \le \liminf_{n \to \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f_n(x)|^2dx \le 1$.